# Constructing a dense subfamily of Gaussian measures

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory

Given $T$ a family of probability measures on $(X, B(X))$ given by collection of Gaussian measures with mean $a$ and variance $b^2$. Find a **sub-family** of $T$ dense in $T$, where a sub-family is **defined** as a set containing **countably many** members of $T$.

**My attempt:** I still got stuck on constructing such subfamily, despite spending several hours on this problem. If anyone could help give some thought, I would sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: What is $X$ here?

Comment: @Michael Greinecker: Thanks for your question. X could be anything I believe.

Comment: The space $X$ should at least allow for some Gaussian measures and therefore be a vector space. Is $X$ finite-dimensional? Separable?

Comment: Also you might want to add whether the subfamily should be countable or should satisfy some other property. Else you could just take $T$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker & Koke-N: We could assume $X=R^n$ in this case. By the way, the subfamily is defined as a set containing countably many members of $T$, and it is *dense* in T if it is equivalent to T.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: could you give this problem a try under the assumption $X$ is a finite-dimensional space (i.e, $X=R^n$)? This problem is quite tricky, as I still have not been able to detect such subfamily yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$, so that $T=\{\gamma(a,b):a\in \mathbb{R},b\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}\}$, where $\gamma(a,b)$ is the Gaussian measure with mean $a$ and variance $b^2$. Since $T$ is dominated by a $\sigma$-finite measure, it is separable w.r.t. the total variation distance $d_{TV}(\gamma_1,\gamma_2)=\sup_{B\in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}}|\gamma_1(B)-\gamma_2(B)|$.

Let $S=\{\gamma(a,b):a\in\mathbb{Q},b\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}\}$. Then $S$ is a countable subfamily of $T$ and its closure is $T$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and
$$
d_{TV}(\gamma_1,\gamma_2)\le \int|\phi(x;a_1,b_1)-\phi(x;a_2,b_2)|dx,
$$
where $\phi(\,\cdot\,;a,b)$ is the pdf corresponding to $\gamma(a,b)$, so that for $\gamma\in T$ and any $\epsilon>0$ we can find $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $b\in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ s.t. $d_{TV}(\gamma,\gamma(a,b))<\epsilon$.

It is also clear that $S$ and $T$ are equivalent families.

Comment: thank you very much for your solution. I wonder why did you pick $X=\mathscr{R}$ rather than $X=\mathscr{R^n}$? Does your solution extend to *any* finite-dimensional space $X$? How about infinite? Also, how is $P$ defined in your solution? Why do we need $T$ is separable, and why the fact that $T$ is dominated by a $\sigma$-finite measure implies separability by total variation distance?

Comment: 1. It also works in $\mathbb{R}^n$. You just need to consider $T=\{\gamma(a,b):a\in \mathbb{R}^n,b\in \Sigma\}$, where $\Sigma$ is the space of positive definite matrices.

Comment: 2. You may choose any other distance depending on the context.

Comment: But then what would $S$ be defined as? Is it simply just $\gamma(a,b): a\in Q^n, b\in Q^n_{>0}$?? And why do we need separable?

Comment: 3. Found this result in Lehman, Romano - "Testing Statistical Hypotheses" (p. 698)

Comment: In this case $S=\{\gamma(a,b):a\in \mathbb{Q}^n,b\in \Sigma'\}$, where $\Sigma'$ is a countable dense subset of $\Sigma$.

Comment: But then how $\sum'$ is dense in $R^n$?

Comment: It is not. But why do you consider $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$? The variance of $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a positive-definite matrix...

Comment: What does this sentence imply: "the variance of $\gamma$ in $\mathscr{R}$ is a PD matrix"??

Comment: It implies that you need to consider only PD matrices for the second parameter (i.e. $\Sigma'$ need not be dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: I still could not get it. Could you please elaborate further on "only PD matrices for the second parameter"??

Comment: You asked "But then how $\Sigma'$ is dense in $R^n$?" $\Sigma'$ should not be dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It should be dense in the space of PD matrices because $b$ ranges over PD matrices (if I understand the question correctly).

Comment: Oh I finally get it. But then how do you prove the inequality for total variation, which becomes $L_{\inf}$ in $R^n$ then?

Comment: What is $L_{\text{inf}}$?

Comment: I mean $L_{\infty}$ norm. What I am thinking is whether your proof in $R^1$ could be extended to $R^n$ without any technical difficulties arising. I know you said Yes, but I wonder if those key steps are still true.

Comment: Why it becomes $L_{\infty}$ in $R^n$?

Comment: I was wrong;p I forgot the gaussian measure would take an n-dimensional input and turn it into real numbers;p Btw, what is $B_R$?

Comment: It is $B(R)$ in your notation

Comment: so I have thought quite a bit about your soluton, and I have one last question: is the inequality on total variation distance $d_{TV}(\gamma_1, \gamma_2)$ validated because $T$ is separable w.r.t that variation distance?

Comment: The inequality helps you to see that $S$ is dense in $T$, i.e. for every $\gamma\in T$ and $\epsilon>0$, $B(\gamma,\epsilon)\cap S\ne \emptyset$ ($B(\gamma,\epsilon)$ is an $\epsilon$-ball around $\gamma$).

Comment: I understand that it helps us show $S$ is dense in $T$, but I thought the reason was because it shows the equivalence between two probability measures of $S$ and $T$. This is not right? I am using the dense definition in the sense of a sub-family of a family of probability measures, not in the sense of Real Analysis (they are equivalent then??)

Comment: What is your reference to "dense definition in the sense of a sub-family"? Anyway, density is a topological notion. So whatever definition is used, you need to define a topology on $T$. In my case it is one induced by $d_{TV}$...

Comment: Thanks for your patience. The definition is: a sub-family $P*$ of $P$ is dense in P if the probability measure of $P*$ is equivalent to the probability measure of $P$. In other words, for your particular solution, I thought you were proving: for any $T_1\in T$ and $S_1\in S$, $T_1<< S_1$ and $S_1<<T_1$. I believe your main inequality showed $T_1<<S_1$, while the separability part implies $S_1<<T_1$. Is this correct?

Comment: Nope. Equivalence is trivial here. Moreover, **any countable subset** of $T$ is **equivalent** to $T$ (we exclude degenerate measures).

Comment: How do you show that "trivial" equivalence then?? That's all I need to show actually;p

Comment: It is trivial because any nondegenerate Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I am sorry, but could you show me how to prove this direction:if $T(A)=0$, then $\lambda(A)=0$? Is it due to the fact that Gaussian measure is only zero on empty set?? Also, I thought the sub-family of $T$ also have Gaussian measures, but the parameters are defined on subsets of $R$, rather than $R$ itself? How could a set with Lebesgue measure be a sub-family of $T$??

Comment: You may want to ask a new question "Why nodegenerate Gaussian measures on $\mathbb{R}$ are equivalent?".

Comment: per your request, here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464001/lebesgue-and-gaussian-measures-are-equivalent-on-rn