# Properties of support of $(R, B(R), P)$

Tags: statistics, measure-theory

Given probability measure space $(R, B(R), P)$. Define support $B$ of $P$ as the set of all points $x\in R$ such that $P(A)>0$ for any open interval $A$ containing $x$. Prove that:

(a) $B$ must be a closed set with $P(B)=1$.

(b) $B$ is the **intersection** of all closed sets $K$ with $P(K)= 1$.

**My attempt:**

**(a)** First, if a point $y\notin B$, then exists an open interval $K$ containing $y$ such that $P(K)= 0$. The union $(\cup_{i\ \in\  N} K_i)$ of every such open intervals $K_i$ corresponding to those points $y_i$ is an open set with $P(\cup_{i\ \in\  N} K_i) = \sum_{i\ \in N} P(K_i) = 0$. And $\cup_{i\ \in N} y_i$ is a collection of points, which are singleton sets, so it's obviously an open set in $R$.

Thus, $(R - \cup_{i\ \in N} y_i) = B$ is a closed set, and $P(R) - P(\cup_{i\ \in N} y_i) = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^N P(y_i) = 1 - 0 = 1$ (because $\sum_{i=1}^N P(y_i)\leq \sum_{i\ \in N} P(K_i) = 0$).

**(b)** I cannot see how to prove this **without** using the theorem: "Two equivalent probability measures on $(R, B(R))$ must have the same support"

**My question:** Could anyone please help review my solution to part (a), or give some thought on part (b)? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a), if $x\notin B$, then there exists an open interval $A$ containing $x$ s.t. $\mathsf{P}(A)=0$. So every point in $B^c$ has an open neighbourhood that lies in $B^c$. So $B^c$ is open. In order to verify that $\mathsf{P}(B^c)=0$, you need to show that $B^c=\bigcup_{x\notin B,x\in \mathbb{Q}}U_x$, where $U_x$ is an open interval containing $x$.

For (b), $B$ is the smallest closed set with $\mathsf{P}(B)=1$. Otherwise, if $B$ is a proper subset of a closed set $B'$ satisfying the condition stated in the question, then for $x\in B'\setminus B$, there exists an open interval $A\in B^c$ containing $x$ s.t. $\mathsf{P}(A)>0$. Thus, $\mathsf{P}(B)<1$ which violates $(a)$.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. But how do we know $B=U^c$?

Comment: Because $B$ is the smallest set satisfying...

Comment: Isn't that what we get ONLY after proving (b)? And for (a), is the reason $P(B^c) = 0$ due to the fact that $P(U_x) = 0$ for every $x\notin B, x\in Q$? Because it's obvious to me that $B^c = \cup_{x\notin B, x\in Q} U_x$, based on the definition of $B$?

Comment: Yes. $B^c$ can be written as a countable union of null sets.

Comment: Then the reason $B=U^c$ is just because we already have $B^c = \cup_{x\notin B, x\in Q} U_x$, isn't it? Thanks a ton!

By the way, could you kindly help with another problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460044/constructing-a-dense-subfamily-of-gaussian-measures?

Comment: what you wrote was correct. But what is it used for? Could you kindly give the problem in the link a try?

Comment: @user177196 Oh. I misread part (b). $B$ should be the intersection of **all** closed sets...

Comment: No worries. Thanks a ton for your help. Can you check out the other problem too?

Comment: I am so sorry, as this might be a dumb question, but do you know what is the rule that allows us to say: $P(R-B^c) = P(R) - P(B^c)$, for $P=$ probability measure on $(R, B(R))$?

Comment: Also, how could you imply $P(B) < 1$?

Comment: Because the complement of $B$ contains a set with positive probability.

Comment: I'm so dumb;p You are saying that set $A$ is contained in $B^c$ and $P(B^c)>P(A)>0$, correct? Thanks a ton if this is the case, as it indeed implies $P(B)<1$.


Btw, could you please help me with another difficult problem here (I have been stucked on it for the last few days already;p): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460044/constructing-a-dense-subfamily-of-gaussian-measures.