# Lebesgue and Gaussian measures are equivalent on R^n

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have been trying to solve a problem involving constructing a **sub-family** $H$ of a family $T$ of **Gaussian** measures on $(R, B(R))$ such that $H$ is dense in $T$ (in the sense that for any probability measures in $H$ and in $T$, they are mutually absolutely continuous). I am wondering how Lebesgue measure and Gaussian measure are **equivalent** in $R$ (I can prove Gaussian is dominated by Lebesgue, but cannot prove the other way). Could someone help me prove this remaining direction?

Comment: A function which is strictly positive always has a strictly positive integral over sets of strictly positive measure.

Comment: @Shalop: thanks a ton for your help! Could you please help with this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460044/constructing-a-dense-subfamily-of-gaussian-measures/2462299?noredirect=1#comment5091161_2462299.